# In Fabric.js is there a way to have a transparent object with a shadow?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

My end goal is to have a blurred poly object. Since there are no filters for objects, only images, I figured I could make the object transparent and use a blurred shadow:

```
const poly = new fabric.Polygon({
  // ...
  fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
  shadow: new fabric.Shadow({
    color: 'red',
    blur: 10,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
  }),
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jhurqgbe/

But the opacity of the shadow is affected by the opacity of the object and it doesn't work. Is there a workaround or another solution altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You should look in this way

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('cnv');

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: 'transparent', // Set to "transparent"
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
});

const drawBlurRect = () => {

  const ctx = canvas.getContext()
  ctx.save()
  ctx.filter = "blur(20px)";
  ctx.rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height)
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.restore()
  
}

canvas.on("after:render", drawBlurRect)

canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
```